# Getting access token from the PayPal API Error

Tags: javascript, paypal

// secrets are defined above (javascript)

```
PAYPAL_OAUTH_API = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token/";

// 1c. Get an access token from the PayPal API
basicAuth = `${PAYPAL_CLIENT}:${PAYPAL_SECRET}`;
const token = await axios.post(
  PAYPAL_OAUTH_API,
  `grant_type=client_credentials`,
  {
    headers: {
      Accept: `application/json`,
      Authorization: `Basic ${basicAuth}`,
    },
  }
);
return token;
```

It gives me error 'Request failed with status code 401
I think the issue is in  `grant_type=client_credentials` syntax.Is this a correct syntax of passing arguments to Axios for making post request.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/get-an-access-token-curl/) those are the correct parameters to the API.

Comment: It's preferable to use `{grant_type: 'client_credentials'}` and Axios will convert it to the URL-encoded string. But what you've written should work.

Comment: 401 error means you didn't give the correct credentials. Are you sure you used your sandbox key rather than the production key?

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/reference/api-responses/#http-status-codes

Comment: @Barmar it worked for me.Thankyou.But now its giving **UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE** error.

Comment: Well try 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${basicAuth}` must be base64 encoded, try `${btoa(basicAuth)}`

curl's -u flag does this for you

Comment: … and so does using the `auth` option of axios to begin with :-)